# Recycleview in coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to create RelativeLayout that has CoordinatorLayout and LinearLayout at bottom and found some strange behavior that I can't resolve. This is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sender"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="?colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messages_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="?colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After changing data in adapter I trying to scroll to last element ( for example by recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(size); )and all I see is part of last view (not full size). If recycleview not nest to CoordinatorLayout - all works as expecting - I see full sized last element view. How can I change layout to works it all correctly ?

Comment: What is the expectation and what is not working..?

Comment: I expect that after scroll to last position i will see last view not cutted. Right now i see only part of view ( seems like it is not scrolled to bottom of last view - just very little part of view visible ). If recycleview move out from CoordinatorLayout all working correct - scrollToPosition works as I expecting - last view visible without cutting anything. But I hope it will same behavior in CoordinatorLayout too

Comment: sorry, forgot to add. I am using LinearLayoutManager and com.android.support:design:22.2.0

Comment: Which version of RecyclerView are you using? If its not  v7:22.2.0 try updating that.

Comment: 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Comment: Same thing here v 22.2.1.0. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: no, right now I do not have any fix. Created ticket for library but now it is not resolved.

Comment: I see the same issue.  Last element in recyclerview gets clipped :-P

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from `Toolbar` and instead add it to `AppBarLayout` so it should be like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be that `smoothScrollToPosition()` will silently scroll `RecyclerView` without letting `CoordinatorLayout` about the scroll being happening. This is what I came up with. Nice thing about it is that it should only scroll `AppBarLayout` if you have enough items in Adapter.

```
    final AppBarLayout layout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    layout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            lastVerticalOffset = verticalOffset;
        }
    });
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (tryCollapseAppbarOnNextScroll && lastVerticalOffset != -layout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
                layout.setExpanded(false);
                tryCollapseAppbarOnNextScroll = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Now whenever you send a message, do this:

```
tryCollapseAppbarOnNextScroll = true;
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
```

The main point is to use to add android:layout_marginBottom to your activity

Answer (score 0):

The last element is clipped because the RecyclerView is not entirely visible on the screen. It is being pushed down by the expanded AppBar. Note that when scrolling manually, the AppBar will shrink as you reach the last element.

What worked best in my case was to simply collapse the AppBar before scrolling:

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appbar);
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

I imagine you could improve on this solution by collapsing it only when needed.

If collapsing the AppBar is not desired, then you could add bottom padding of the same height as the expanded AppBar. However, there will be other glitches (e.g. when scrolling to a position which is already in the RecyclerView, but just outside of the screen)